# If we can input in list by loop? if yes then how?

Tags: python

how we can input in list by using for loop?

I can just input list by single line input command.

`nlist=list(input("enter your list items :"))`

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you elaborate with what you've tried and what the expected output is?

Comment: i just want to input some data in list with for loop.

Comment: What are the inputs?  Do you expect them to be comma separated?  Is it meant to be a list of strings?  ints?  What have you tried?  I don't think your code does what you think it does. :-(  Can you show a sample input and the desired result?

Comment: yes i want them in comma separated with type of strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
nlist=str(input("enter your list items separated by , :")).split(',')
```

Comment: I would go a little further and strip off white space from the front and back: `nlist = [x.strip() for x in str(input("enter your list items separated by , :")).split(',')]`

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24076589).